# Ubuntu 19.10 NVidia Optimus not working

Tags: graphics, nvidia-optimus

thank you pilot6 for your message. The requested output is

```
arpad@arpad-P170EM:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
        DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
        Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104M [GeForce GTX 675MX] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer GK104M [GeForce GTX 675MX]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
arpad@arpad-P170EM:~$
```

Many thanks for your help and contribution!
Arpad
I have installed the nvidia driver from the software center but the Steam games still are using intel graphics. Please do you have any ideas how to solve this?
thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Arpad, run `prime-select query` to check which graphic card is in use. To change between Intel and Nvidia, run `sudo prime-select <graphic_card_name>`, replace <graphic_card_name> with `nvidia` or `intel` then restart your computer to apply the changes.

Comment: prime-select query returned nvidia but Steam settings still showed intel card was in use.

Answer (score 0):

Call `sudo prime-select nvidia` anyway. Then reboot.

That helped me in a similar situation.